# XAMPP DirectiveIndex issue (php development)

Tags: php, apache, xampp, config

I'm having an issue with using XAMPP and the ability to use an includes folder in php etc. I'm learning how to use a single point access for my php files, by that I mean, you put only an index.php in the main folder to be accessed and it is it use classes that are located in the Includes folder outside the public_php folder.

Here is the current config inside the httpd.conf (located in the apache2 folder)

```
Here is the current config : 

Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

Here is a screenshot of my file structure, is someone able to help me on how to use the DirectoryIndex setting so that my program is able to just use the require_once 'bla/bla.php';

[image: File structure screenshot]

Thanks for any contribution given.

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` (and it's other variations) include files locally.

You don't have to use your alias to access them, **just write the full local path**:

if you file is located at `/Applications/XAMPP/bla/bla.php`:

```
require_once('/Applications/XAMPP/bla/bla.php');
```

Comment: So basically, I shouldn't have to do anything - am I just placing the files in the wrong directories? The thing is, at my university the amp stack which is preinstalled has a public_php folder, and an includes folder at the same level. Inside the public_php folder has aother folder with the index.php and with the require_once() it allows the file to be used from the includes folder which is at the same level as the public_php - it's really weird